# Deleting a row from JQuery Jtable Client Side only

Tags: jquery-jtable

I am trying to delete a row from JTable in client side only.But somehow i am not able to get the value of the key of the selected record.See the code below

```
            deleteAction :  function (postData) {
                var row_id = $('.jtable-data-row').attr('data-record-key');
                $('#AuthorTableContainer').jtable('deleteRecord', {
                key: row_id,
                clientOnly:true
                });
            }},
```

The problem is when the table contains the multiple record.then in that case "tr" attributes become

"jtable-data-row jtable-row-even" in that case i am not able to get the value of the data-record-key.

Is there any other way to  delete a row from JTable from client side only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is

```
deleteAction :  function (data) {
    $('#AuthorTableContainer').jtable('deleteRecord', {
        key: data.keyValue,
        clientOnly:true
    });
}},
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove a row from a `JTable`, you will need to remove the target row from the underlying `TableModel`. If, for instance, your `TableModel` is an instance of `DefaultTableModel`, you can remove a row by doing the following:

```
((DefaultTableModel)myJTable.getModel()).removeRow(rowToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete any record from jtable and you only know key that's what with my case just pass it like below.

$('#detailVoucherTable').jtable('deleteRecord', { key: 0, clientOnly:true });

Regards
mOOn
digitaal.logix@gmail.com